# How to change target api level when building by EAS(Expo Application Services)

Tags: expo, google-play-console, eas

Google Play Store needs target API Level to be at least 31 now. I built an app through "eas build -p android" command but it makes app with target API 30. So Google Play Store do not accept it.
I also tried building through Expo. But Google Play Console gives an error about invalid key.
I cannot eject expo, because then I will have to do many modifications.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

For those who were lost like I was (had the same questions but for other API levels):

- Update to the latest version of EAS CLI (if you use it): `npm i -g eas-cli`.
- Install the new version of the Expo package: `npm install expo@^49.0.0` or `yarn add expo@^49.0.0`
- Upgrade all dependencies to match SDK 49: `npx expo install --fix`

Build it again (for this post: `eas build -p android`, in my case `npx eas-cli build -p android`).

More instructions here: https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740